структуры рекламного текста / структуры рекламных текстов
Если есть как минимум 5 различных структур для рекламного текста, по которым пишутся новые рекламные текста с разными идеями, то какое окончание будет у слова?

Kiko, только не текста́, а те́ксты.

Правильно:
Существует как минимум 5 различных структур для рекламного текста, по которым пишутся новые рекламные тексты с разными идеями.
Вероятно, есть основная структура и пять ее вариантов.
Сравнить:  Структура рекламного текста
Структура рекламного текста
Существует две категории рекламного текста: выделенный и основной... Рекламный текст состоит из пяти основных элементов, которые почти всегда используются в рекламе: 1) заголовок; 2) подзаголовок; 3) основной текст; 4) подписи и комментарии;
5) рекламный лозунг (слоган).

Спасибо! Просто у меня заголовок «Кратко про структуры рекламного текста». Я не могу понять, какое окончание мне ставить. Кратко про структуры рекламных текстов или кратко про структуры рекламного текста?

Тогда так. Если вы рассказываете о конкретных структурных вариантах, то нужно написать: «Кратко про структуры рекламных текстов». Если вы рассказываете про основную структуру (как в приведенной статье), то нужно написать: «Кратко про структуру рекламного текста». То есть нужно соответствие содержания и   заголовка.   Вроде бы так)
